# Mongo filter results by distinct field

Tags: mongodb

I use this ruby driver for mongo : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver

I have many documents in a collection like this :

```
{
  "_productId" => 10
  ....
}
{
  "_productId" => 10
  ....
}
{
  "_productId" => 12
  ....
}
```

What is the request to get all documents with a distinct "_productId", I mean I want to take the first and the last collection item in this exemple.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)?

Comment: On what basis would you select the first item over the second item?

Answer (score 1):

@db['collection'].distinct('_productId')

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

http://wiki.summercode.com/mongodb_aggregation_functions_and_ruby_counting_and_grouping

Answer (score 1):

With the basis of selecting a document from a group being unknown, and assuming the first document for each `productid` to be selected is based on their insertion order, you can use the aggregation `$group`,`$project` operators together.

Group all the records based on their `productId`, choose the `first` document from each group.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":"$_productId","distinct_doc":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$project:{"distinct_doc":1,"_id":0}}
])
```

If you have an _id field for each document, the first document would be the one which was inserted first for that particular group. If you choose to do it based on some other field, then you would need to perform an additional `$sort` operation before you group the records.

for example,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$sort:{"someField":1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$_productId","distinct_doc":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$project:{"distinct_doc":1,"_id":0}}
])
```

In this case the first document per group, would be the one which comes top when sorted.